# Python logging: show variable name without specifying it explicitly

Tags: python

A lot of the Python code that I write looks something like this:

```
import logging
import shlex
import subprocess

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def execute(system_command, **kwargs):
    """Execute a system command, with sane defaults."""
    # Question is mainly about these two lines:
    logger.info("system_command: '%s'", system_command)
    logger.debug("kwargs: %s", kwargs)
    process = subprocess.run(
        shlex.split(system_command),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        **kwargs)
    if process.returncode != 0:
        logger.info(process.stdout.strip())
        logger.error(process.stderr.strip())
    return process
```

The logging statements are typically added when I am trying to debug something, but then i forget to remove them and they stay there.

My question is: "Does this code look reasonable?". Is there a way for me to write `logger.debug(arg1)` and the logger to automatically show the name of the variable being printed, for the sake of DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good for narrowing down dirty fixes. I used to do this, but don't think it's the correct solution to the problem. Instead if you make smaller functions that are less complicated, and you have a test suite to test these functions, you should reduce the amount of bugs that you have, and not need this. The only time I used something like this, other than when I was debugging, was for a school project that was anal about logging.

---

You're correct, this isn't very DRY. To make it dry however would be best with a decorator, and [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature).
This way, you can use the standard decorator sugar, to allow for easily toggleable debugging on the functions.
This for example could be:

```
@log(logger, debug=False)
def fn(arg1, arg2):
    ...

@log(logger, debug=True)
def fn(arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

The difference being that the second turns debugging on, where the former doesn't. It won't show anything.
Doing this, you can also include default arguments and types to every function, *without any extra effort*.
To do this could be with:

```
from inspect import signature, Parameter
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
DEBUG = True


def log(logger_=None, debug=False):
    debug = DEBUG and debug
    if logger_ is None:
        logger_ = logger
    def wrapper(fn):
        sig = signature(fn)
        formats = {}
        for name, param in sig.parameters.items():
            fmt = '{}() {}'.format(fn.__name__, name)
            if param.annotation is not Parameter.empty:
                fmt += ': {0.__name__}'.format(param.annotation)
            if param.default is not Parameter.empty:
                fmt += '={!r}'.format(param.default)
            fmt += ' -> {value}'
            formats[name] = fmt
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if debug:
                ba = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
                ba.apply_defaults()
                for key, value in ba.arguments.items():
                    logger_.debug(formats[key].format(value=value))
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper


@log(debug=True)
def execute(system_command, **kwargs):
    process = subprocess.run(
        shlex.split(system_command),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        **kwargs)
    if process.returncode != 0:
        logger.info(process.stdout.strip())
        logger.error(process.stderr.strip())
    return process

@log(debug=True)
def test(a: int, b:str='b'):
    return a, b

test(1)
# Displays:
# test() a: int -> 1
# test() b: str='b' -> b
```

Also I'd not be surprised if there is a somewhat large performance difference, with and without the occurrence of `@log`. Which should be something to keep in mind.